# Cannot Draw To HTML 5 Canvas from Data Uri

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filereader

I have been trying for hours and am getting frustrated. My Data Uri image will not write to my canvas for unknown reasons ....

Here is my code ...

```
function addImage() {

var allfiles = $("#postAttachPhoto")[0].files;
var container = $("#ajaxImageContainer");
var linkContainer = $("#scrapedLinkContainer");
var imagePreview = $("#previewImages");
var textArea = $("#postTextArea");



// Handle Inserting The Image Container and Adjusting Sizes
if (!container.is(':visible')) {
    container.show();
    textArea.removeClass('imgPad');
textArea.removeClass('bothPad');
textArea.removeClass('linkPad');

    // is the link ele visible?
    if (!linkContainer.is(':visible')) {
        textArea.addClass('imgPad');
    }
    else{
        textArea.addClass('bothPad');
        container.addClass('linkMargin');
    }
}

$(allfiles).each(function () {
    var file = $(this);
    var mime = file[0].type;
    var reader = new FileReader();


    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var imageSource = e.target.result;

        var image = new Image();
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var imagePreview = $("#previewImages");
        var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

        canvas.id = "canvas_"+number;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var resize = {};

        image.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
            resize = calculateAspectRatioFit(image.width,image.height,'200','1000');
            canvas.width = resize.width;
            canvas.height = resize.height;
            imagePreview.append(canvas);

            /*var previewImage = $("<img onClick='rotateImage(this);'/>");
        previewImage.attr("style", "width:250px;");
        previewImage.attr("src", e.target.result);
        previewImage.attr("class", 'previewImg');
        previewImage.attr("class", 'previewImg');
        previewImage.attr("id", 'previewImg_' + number);
        imagePreview.append(previewImage);
        */
        };
        image.src = imageSource;


    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);


});
autosize.update(textArea);
}
```

Note: the commented out code works for displaying via an image tag.
Main objective is to be able to modify this image, by allowing 90 degree rotates. it didnt work from the img tag so im trying to load into canvas.

Comment: What is in `allfiles`? Can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You never add your canvas to the DOM.... ie `document.body.appendChid(canvas)`, so how do you know it isn't writing to it if you can't see it. Also no reason to do this `file = $(this)`

Comment: All files is a file input.
Also, Its missing the code where it adds it to the dom, but it is.
The canvas element is just transparent.

Comment: Can you do the `ctx.drawImage()` call after you've changed that canvas' width&height? Resetting the width&height probably clears your canvas.

Comment: @ManuelOtto Nail on the Head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue lied within changing the canvas size after loading the image.
After removing sizing components the code worked well!

Thanks to @Manuel Otto for the help.